# Converting a KeyValuePair collection in to anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to convert a a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` of KeyValuePair to an anonymous type?

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.add("first", "hello");
dict.add("second", "world");

var anonType = new{dict.Keys[0] = dict[0], dict.Keys[1] = dict[1]};

Console.WriteLine(anonType.first);
Console.WriteLine(anonType.second);

********************output*****************
hello
world
```

The reason i would like to do this is because I am retrieving an object from a webservice that represents an object that does not exist in the wsdl.  The returned object only contains a KeyValuePair collection that contains the custom fields and their values.  These custom fields can be named anything, so i cant really map an xml deserialization method to the final object i will be using (whose properties must be bound to a grid).

*Just because I used `Dictionary<string,string>` does not mean it is absolutely a dictionary, i just used it for illustration.  Really its an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

Ive been trying to thing of a way to do this, but am drawing a blank.  This is c# .NET 4.0.

Comment: You want dynamic typing, not an anonymous type. So you should look into C# 4's `dynamic` feature.

Comment: You're saying (a) you don't know that "first" or "second" will really be there, they could be anything, yet (b) you want to be able to code `anonType.first` and `anonType.second`?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), it is based on a dictionary.

Comment: That uses dynamic typing. Anonymous types are something different.

Comment: @CodeInChaos The OP wants to be able to write `anonType.first`, `anonType.second`. This looks like a dynamic object, not an anonymous one.

Comment: hmm you're right. The wrong terminology threw me off. Really looks like he wants dynamic typing.

Comment: @CodeInChaous The title does say anonymous type, but the syntax is clearly dynamic typing. Since he specified .NET 4 then dynamic seems like the best route to achieve the syntax.

Comment: I was hoping that i could write some reflection to add the properties rather than using dynamic.

Comment: Using `ExpandoObject` still requires an assumption about what will actually be there, doesn't it? In his case `first` and `second` might be `foo`, `bar`, and a dozen other different things.

Comment: you won't escape dynamic if you want to write `anonType.first`.

Comment: @Mike why would you rather use reflection than dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of ways to achieve this, but actually converting it in the same Dictionary seems a bit odd to do.

One way to accomplish this, by not actually converting everyting is the following:

```
public class MyDictionary<T,K> : Dictionary<string,string> // T and K is your own type
{
    public override bool TryGetValue(T key, out K value)
    {
        string theValue = null;
        // magic conversion of T to a string here
        base.TryGetValue(theConvertedOfjectOfTypeT, out theValue);
        // Do some magic conversion here to make it a K, instead of a string here
        return theConvertedObjectOfTypeK;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ExpandoObject is the best option, which I believe is a wrapper around some XML.  You could also use an XElement:

```
var result = new XElement("root");
result.Add(new XElement("first", "hello"));
result.Add(new XElement("second", "world"));

Console.WriteLine(result.Element("first").Value); 
Console.WriteLine(result.Element("second").Value);

foreach (var element in result.Elements())
    Console.WriteLine(element.Name + ": " + element.Value);
```

I haven't used ExpandoObject, so I'd try that first because I understand it does exactly what you want and is also something new and interesting to learn.